# Capitalize the freebsd documentation tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, documentation, documentation-tags

From what I see, the most popular tags in Documentation (like Android or JavaScript Language) are stylized properly.

Is it possible / what's the procedure to change freebsd to FreeBSD in Documentation?

Comment: Find someone 20k+ and ask them to set the Friendly Name in the tag wiki.

Comment: I changed it to [FreeBSD](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/freebsd/topics). As @JF noted, this is set in the tag wiki Friendly Name.

Comment: @JonEricson Should we make a canonical question for this?

Comment: @JonEricson I'm over 20k rep and I just can't find that *friendly name* field you're talking about.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: Can you see it when you [edit the tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/2796)?

Comment: @JonEricson that's where I searched, I can only see the excerpt, body, preview and edit summary

Comment: @JF: Probably. One of the things I wanted to document was how the Friendly Name is filled in during the commitment process. I think that needs to be reworked a bit, but I don't have the bandwidth to think about it today. It occurs to me that it should be an editable field for all committers at any point before creation.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: Ok. I'm not sure the option has been made available to non-employees yet. If you can't see it, then it must not have been.

Comment: @JonEricson I was able to edit the friendly name of the [tag:maven] tag yesterday, so perhaps the option is being made available right now to 20kers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FreeBSD documentation tag is now stylized properly.